# Open desire layout while launching the app in circlePageIndicator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I am using CirclePageIndicator to make my application. It has three layouts left, middle and right layouts. When app is launched it goes to left layout. I want it to be in middle layout. Any help please? 
My code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    PagerAdapter adapter = new CircularPagerAdapter();
    mPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    CirclePageIndicator circleIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    circleIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
    final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    circleIndicator.setFillColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    circleIndicator.setStrokeColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    circleIndicator.setStrokeWidth(1);
    circleIndicator.setRadius(6 * density);
}
```

Comment: have you add setCurrentItem line after this circleIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it you use a `ViewPager` to control your layout. Use

```
myViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

The indicator has nothing to do with it.

Comment: That's odd. Nothing happens? The Layout doesn't change?

Comment: Layout changes but after launching the app for first time it is in layout left. I want in layout middle.

Comment: So oyu mean the content of the screen is changed but the Indicator is on left? If so, use setCurrentItem() AFTER you initialized the indicator and tied it to the viewpager.

Comment: Well, it's still very unclear what you're asking. Does the ViewPager set the incorrect page? Does the Indicator indicate the incorrect page?

Comment: View pager is setting correct page. The only thing is that I want to see the middle layout when the app is launched. Thatś it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55464/discussion-between-ascorbin-and-bshah).

Comment: Surprisingly it is working with the same method but the circles are not moving when the page is changes. Why?